# GTmetrix about speed issue

Tags: wordpress, performance, themes, gtmetrix

I am new here and I was recommended by someone from Hostinger. The guy who was developing my website just needed to move away and now I will try to contact someone new. I was checking that the webpage is too slow, so I am now trying to understand more before handing it to a new developer. Is there anything I can do without big knowledge? The website is [www.shop-tgu.com](http://www.shop-tgu.com)

Here is what GTmetrix found:

Foto [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qLoE.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rUCi.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKnPW.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow34x.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0j35.png

Very thankful for every little help that I can use to improve it.
Have a nice week everyone

Answer (score 0):

I can see you already used Cloudflare For Caching. It is good sign. Most of the reasons why loading happens are using many plugins and they load tons of js and css files. These files delay the page load. You can reduce by using plugin like 'Profiler' to check which plugins cause the page loading most(delete after used). Then try using 'Swift Performance' or 'Asset CleanUp' plugins to manage minify the css and js file or remove on specific page. If you are not familiar, suggest to get help from developer.